# What if I detach AVR micro controller from the Arduino Board after uploading program?

Tags: avr

What if I detach AVR microcontroller from the Arduino Board after uploading program? Does the microcontroller still have the program on it? Or the program will be deleted?

On the board where does Arduino store hex file?

I am very beginner in Embedded Programming. I am learning about microcontroller and Arduino. While learning about programming Arduino-Uno I got these question in my mind.

Comment: the microcontroller itself stores the program in flash, so you can remove the part and move it elsewhere and the program goes with it.

Comment: Just look at the documentation for the AVR part it describes where the application lives.

Comment: historically there have been boards (basic stamp, etc) that the program on the microcontroller was an interpreter for a bytecode that actually lived on another device on the board, eeprom or flash.  No reason to do this on an arduino, since you are learning examine the schematic and see what else you see on the board, where else could the program live?  (combined with reading datasheets for the parts you find)

Comment: Make sure to check this link (https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/standalone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AVR µC got a flash memory that can store the code loaded in. That mean you can load the code with the arduino board, detach the avr and put it on another circuit. If the µC is powered well, it will behave just like the arduino.

Don't forget to set the /reset pin to high, if you do, the µC will be stuck to the 1st line of code ;)